# Join every each two array into single element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

I have array like this

```js
[
  '7 10 8',
  '6 0 0 1 5 1 1 0',
  '7 10 7',
  '1 1 1 1 1 1 1',
  '3 9 7',
  '3 3 3 4 3 3 3'
]
```

i want to narrow down the element and join every two array

expected output

```js
[
  '7 10 8|6 0 0 1 5 1 1 0',
  '7 10 7|1 1 1 1 1 1 1',  
  '3 9 7|3 3 3 4 3 3 3'
]
```

Comment: What if there's an odd number of elements?

Comment: doesn't matter. in my case the array length will always even

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple for loop:

```js
const myArray = [
      '7 10 8',
      '6 0 0 1 5 1 1 0',
      '7 10 7',
      '1 1 1 1 1 1 1',
      '3 9 7',
      '3 3 3 4 3 3 3'
    ];

    const outputArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i = i + 2)
    {
        outputArray.push(myArray[i] + '|' + myArray[i + 1]);
    }

    console.log(outputArray)
```

In this loop, instead of iterating over every element, you are iterating over every other element, which is why `i = i + 2` is used.

Comment: It's probably worth noting *why* this works. The key here is `i = i + 2`